# Listen to changes in webview with contenteditable div

Tags: android, webview

In a WebView on the Android platform, is it possible to listen to when a div that is marked with contenteditable=true is edited?

If it is not possible, what would be my next best option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you own the web page loaded in the WebView?

Javascript runs in the WebView can interact with the host Android app ([see this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript)), and it seems that the listening can be done in javascript ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256342/trigger-an-event-when-contenteditable-is-changed)), so if you can modify the web page and add a callback to Android java code then it can be done.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I do own the web page. The javascript you proposed didn't do exactly what I wanted but it lead me to find this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979738/fire-jquery-event-on-div-change which works great.

Comment: @NickLH Can I ask you how you exactly implemented it in the end (if you still remember)?

Comment: If you follow the link in my previous message you will see the following code: $('#myDiv').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(event)

That was enough for it to work for me. If you need something more complicated then this might not be enough...