# Django table2: Add row with the edittext field

Tags: django

I have designed the the table with the table2.is the screen shot of my table as shown below:

[image: Screen shot of table]

This row of each column are read only i.e. screenshot.I want the row of each column should be editable.Can we have the "edittext" as column of each row in the table2 in django?

Below is my model.py

```
from django.db import models

    class Person(models.Model):
        date = models.CharField(verbose_name="Date",max_length=255)
        project = models.CharField(verbose_name="Project",max_length=255)
        release = models.CharField(verbose_name="Release",max_length=255)
        feature = models.CharField(verbose_name="Feature",max_length=255)
        module_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Module Name",max_length=255)
        hours_spent = models.CharField(verbose_name="Hours spent",max_length=255)
        comment = models.CharField(verbose_name="Comment",max_length=255)
```

Below is the table.py.

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Person

class PersonTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        # add class="paleblue" to <table> tag
        attrs = {'class': 'paleblue'}
        #fields = ('name') # fields to display
```

How should I edit my model.py,table.py? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To make cells editable you can use `html5` [contenteditable](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp) attribute.

So you need to have this attribute in each `td` of your table.
You can specify `td` attributes in `Column` definition:

```
class ProductsTable(tables.Table):
    date = tables.columns.Column(verbose_name="Date",max_length=255,attrs={'td': {'contenteditable': ''}})
```

or you can probably override `__init__` method of the table to add this attribute to every column so you don't have to specify it multiple times.

This makes your table `editable` but it doesn't mean that you can modify your database through this table yet. You will have to do some magic with `AJAX` and event handling.

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6256386/3371056)