# How to get the new text of a content editable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div class="custom_title" contenteditable="true" maxlength="50">
   WRITE YOUR CUSTOM TITLE HERE
</div>
```

Then I do:

```
$("#search_wiki").on("click", function() {
  myGoogle();
});
```

Which calls:

```
var termS;  
function myGoogle() {
  termS = $(".custom_title").html();
  console.log(termS);
```

Yet when I change the text on that div, the console stills gives me the old text and not the new one

Comment: put the initialization inside the function `var termS;`

Comment: i'll give it another try yet wasn't working as it is not picking up the new text changes

Comment: works fine at https://jsfiddle.net/84n6tdm1/

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli yes exactly I'd expect it, driving me a bit mad on here

Comment: also you can have something like this only `$("#search_wiki").on("click", myGoogle);`

Comment: @guradio that's neat, thanks

Comment: going to try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6256386/1018804

Comment: Look at my following answer: it's working. this is the formal way by JQuery.

Comment: Is jQuery loaded already?

Answer (score 1):

It works fine in the snippet:

```js
$("#search_wiki").on("click", function() {
  myGoogle();
});

var termS;  
function myGoogle() {
  termS = $(".custom_title").html();
  console.log(termS);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom_title" contenteditable="true" maxlength="50">
   WRITE YOUR CUSTOM TITLE HERE
</div>

<h1 id="search_wiki">Search wiki</h1>
```

Comment: yeah.. but not working on here, i'm going to try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6256386/1018804

Answer (score 0):

**Just add jQuery on events inside ready event like this:**

```
<script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search_wiki").on("click", function() {
      myGoogle();
    });
  });
```

and the html as you made:

```
<div class="custom_title" contenteditable="true" maxlength="50">
  WRITE YOUR CUSTOM TITLE HERE
</div>
<h1 id="search_wiki">Search wiki</h1>
```