# How to write event listener for all elements in a particular tag at once?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write an Event listener function that needs to be called when any element in my `<ul>` tag gets edited.
For example for elements in given ul

```
<ul class="container">
  <h4 contenteditable="true">hi</h4>
  <h5 contenteditable="true">hi</h5>
  <label>
    <input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
    <span contenteditable="true">Indeterminate Style</span>
  </label>
  <p contenteditable="true">hi</p>
  <blockquote contenteditable="true">sup</blockquote>
</ul>
```

I want to use `element.addEventListener()` only once (I cannot just declare contenteditable for `ul` and add listener for same as that produces undesirable UI changes). Also, if possible I want to declare `onchange` for all these element at once(like from css).

I want to do this because I am adding elements dynamically and want to remove redundant code.

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery or just plain JavaScript?

Comment: I have never used it but this might be the time to learn. @Si8

Comment: I think most often you'll see a collection of elements and have event listeners applied to them in a loop.  Word of caution though, dynamically added elements may not inherit an event listener.

Comment: Could you go into detail about your *only once* and *at once* phrasing?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript (adding event listeners to dynamic elements)

Comment: jQuery has a `.on()` handler which handles static and dynamic content change listener. It also needs to be added once and handles every element that matches the selector defined.

Comment: @Doug +1 for beating me to it... :)

Comment: @Doug That does work for click but not for change

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because editing a `contenteditable` element doesn't fire the `change` event in the first place. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events

Comment: @Barmar I don't think this question should be closed as a duplicate of the other question.  This is about JavaScript, that was about jQuery (a specific library).  Now this question is locked to those that want to submit Vanilla JS answers

Comment: @vol7ron Although the question says jQuery, there are vanilla JS answers there as well.

Comment: @vol7ron I've added the dupe that Doug mentioned, it's just plain JS.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for the update, the combination should suffice.  It's of my opinion, which might differe from the community's, that the answers shouldn't be used to justify duplicates as they could be orphaned, deleted, or significantly changed by the owners; whereas questions aren't typically modified as often.  How does one remove their "reopen" vote?

Comment: @vol7ron You can't remove a reopen vote, only a close vote. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193061/ability-to-retract-reopen-delete-votes

Comment: My dupe-close philosophy is if the questions are similar enough, and "has an answer here" is true, I'll use it. Trying to find an "exact duplicate" is too narrow a target.

Comment: That sounds like a safe strategy, since we've already invested enough time to adminsitrating this question ;)

Comment: @Barmar similar enough? The questions you linked are to "add event to dynamically created elements" and mine is to "add a common event to all elements in tag". It just so happens that same solution works for both cases. Check 3rd para of "when two questions are duplicates" https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844. Finding "exact duplicate" is too narrow target? Seriously? Also, what's the point of marking a question after it has been answered (thanks to the active community)?

Comment: @Lcukerd You said "I want to do this because I am adding elements dynamically". That's the essential part of the problem, and it's the same as what those other questions are about, and the solutions are the same.

Comment: From the meta answer you linked to: **Questions may be duplicates if they have the same (potential) answers. This includes not only word-for-word duplicates, but also the same idea expressed in different words.**

Comment: @barmar that was added for support and to prevent comments like "but you can just declare same event functions for each" , not including that does not affect my question. "same idea expressed in different words" I am not sure about the same idea part. Anyway, if you have decided to keep this question closed then I can't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the second answer here: [trigger an event when contenteditable is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256342/trigger-an-event-when-contenteditable-is-changed/33113756)
You can do this for all the contenteditable elements inside your ul

```
$( "ul.container" ).on( "focus", "[contenteditable=true]", function() {
  //here you save the content innerhtml/text, etc of the element
});
```

then with the "blur" event, when you leave an element you can test if the old content is the same and then perform some action.
For reference on the "on" jquery function: http://api.jquery.com/on/