# html5, what is isContentEditable?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

chrome supports the `isContentEditable` property (lists it in the "Inspect Element"), but reports `false` for INPUT, FORM - actually, everything.

too me, for example, seems that INPUT, non-readonly, should be true.

does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: [What](http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable) [is](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable) [`isContentEditable`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`isContentEditable` doesn't have anything to do with forms and input boxes.
It was designed to be a way to flag inline editable html content.

You can see a working example here: http://www.navioo.com/javascript/dhtml/isContentEditable_Example_4513.html

You can read about it

here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090423/editing.html

or: http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable

Comment: thanks!  two questions: one, do you know of a link on how to use contentEditable, eg, how do you know if a user entered a change, and two, is there a single attribute to know if a normal HTMLElement is enterable, eg, INPUT?

Comment: 1) im pretty sure it is not commonly used because it doesn't have standard events thrown like onEdited or anything. You can find some answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events

Comment: 2) Cant you can just check if its an input or a textarea? is anything else "enterable"?

Comment: 1) thanks, 2) input, textarea (not readonly), checkbox, radio, and new HTML5 types and widgets - was after safe and a little future-proof

Comment: checkboxes, radio buttons and the new html5 types are all `input` tags. only `textarea` and `select` aren't i think.

Comment: `contenteditable` is very widely used. Nearly all web-based WYSIWYG editors such as TinyMCE and CKEditor use it, for example. You're right that event support isn't great, though hopefully the HTML5 `input` event will make it into contenteditable elements soon.

Answer (score 3):

An element's `isContentEditable` property, in browsers which support it, tells you whether the immediate child content of the element is editable. It applies specifically to regular non-interactive content (i.e. not form controls), which can be made editable using the `contenteditable` attribute:

```
<div contenteditable="true">This text is all <i>editable</i></div>
```

The `isContentEditable` property of both the `<div>` and the `<i>` elements above will report `true`. However, be aware that not every browser that supports `contentEditable` also supports `isContentEditable`: Firefox 3.x, for example, supports `contentEditable` but [not `isContentEditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.isContentEditable).

`contenteditable` is standardized in HTML5 but has been around for over a decade. It was first introduced in IE 5.5 in 2000 and eventually made its way into other browsers several years later. Firefox has had it since version 3.0 (although it had the document-wide equivalent `designMode` since pre-1.0) and Safari since (I think) 2.0.

Here's a good summary of the history of contentEditable: http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable

Comment: thanks. @icchanobot pointed out the site and purpose - never knew any of that existed!  sounds very nice - as one comment said, "goodbye textarea" - now researching how to use and how well supported - for example, caniuse.com does not list it, and some comments saying Safari for phone does not support.

Comment: @cc: Oh yes, I hadn't spotted I'd duplicated @icchanobot's link. `contenteditable` isn't supported in Safari in iOS yet, but will be in iOS 5.