# contenteditable browser support, does it work in browsers that doesn't support html5

Tags: html, contenteditable, browser-support

I read that contenteditable is new in HTML5 and in list of browser support for contenteditable  shows that IE 5.5+ supports it.

I just got confused. as far as I know IE6 for instance doesn't support HTML5. if its new in HTML5 how is it possible that IE6 supports it. If it doesn't work in lower versions of IE then  how does it support it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497680/html5-what-is-iscontenteditable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not new in HTML5, it's just been standardized by the WHATWG.

Please see: http://caniuse.com/#search=contenteditable and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable

Comment: so can say that its compatible with almost all browsers?

Comment: Yes, it's fully compatible with current browsers except Opera Mini.