# Listening to events of a  contenteditable HTML element 

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mutation-events

I'm trying to figure out if there is any way to listen to events like `focus` or `change` of an HTML element with `contenteditable` attribute.

I have this html markup:

```
<p id="test" contenteditable >Hello World</p>
```

I've tried these without any success([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/upidak/edit#javascript,html,live)):

```
var test = document.querySelector('#test');
test.addEventListener('change', function(){
  alert('content edited');
}, false);
test.addEventListener('DOMCharacterDataModified', function(){
  alert('content edited');
}, false);
test.addEventListener('focus', function(){
  alert('content edited');
}, false);
```

I don't want to listen to keyboard or mouse events. I didn't find any clear documentation in [**W3C**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable) and [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_Editable) about `contenteditable`.

Is it possible to listen to `change` and `focus` or other events on a content editable HTML element?

Comment: Checkout the second answer to this question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not really. There is no `change` event for `contenteditable` elements, and there's no HTML5 `input` event either, although I think that will eventually appear. It's a pain.

---

**UPDATE 23 June 2012**

Recent WebKit supports the HTML5 `input` event on `contenteditable` elements, as does Firefox 14.

---

`focus`, however, does work, as does `DOMCharacterDataModified` in most browsers (though notably not IE < 9). See http://jsfiddle.net/UuYQH/112/

By the way, `contenteditable` is not a Boolean attribute: it requires a value, which should be one of "true", "false", "inherit" and the empty string (which is equivalent to "true").

Comment: Thanks, your fiddle is not working in my Chrome. Also `contenteditable` is correct based on docs I think

Comment: @Mohsen: Works for me in Chrome. It probably isn't clear, but the idea is to type in the contenteditable div at the top rather than the texarea, which is there to log events.

Comment: @Mohsen: I should have added a link to the HTML5 spec for the `contenteditable` attribute. Here it is: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable

Comment: It seems it changed, it used to be as I wrote. Anyway contenteditable without any value is working fine

Comment: @Mohsen: I don't think it changed. I've used these events occasionally on Chrome for quite a long time.

Comment: Your fiddle is a little misleading, I typed in the `<textarea/>` instead of `<p/>` element, nothing happened then I found myself typed in the wrong area..

Answer (score 2):

I know this is kinda late but jQuery seems to work with focus, check this example out:

http://jsfiddle.net/powerphillg5/EGtSC/

```
$("#test").focus(function(){
     $("#log").append("<li>Item Focused</li>");
});
```

I hope this helps, but if it's not what you were looking for I will humbly accept the votes down.

Answer (score 2):

Blur (when the area loses focus) and focus both works. At least with jQuery.
Tested with Chrome 28 and Safari 6.

```
$("#test").blur(function(){
  $("#log").append("<li>Item lost focus</li>");
});
```

Comment: This is by far the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

contenteditable was introduced way back in IE 5.5, it was supported by the JavaScript 1.1 / 1.2 API and applied first to iframes, later to DIV's. Its supported in all browsers to some degree. Now in the HTML5 spec most elements can accept this attribute (but beware backwards compatibility). onchange event support may apply still to form elements as it was originally designed, having little to do with this attribute. Your option is still keypress events, which are easy to capture and when combined with a check for the target elements focus you have a similar result to onchange. It might not be ideal for edge cases but for most use cases I would go this route and its the most backwards compatible too.