# how to change the table cell color using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I having a html table with inline edit function,when the user edit the td if the value enter by user lower than zero the td color for specific cell would change without refreshing the page.

For example: if cell =< "-1", `background-color=#FF0000`

there is any way to make this work in reality?

```
$("#table td").each( function() {
    var thisCell = $(this);
    var cellValue = parseInt(thisCell.text());        
    if (!isNaN(cellValue) && (cellValue >=0)) {
        thisCell.css("background-color","#FF0000");
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes.  onChange, set the class name to indicate a custom styling.

Comment: can you please provide some example ...

Comment: Sure.  Will you provide some code showing what you're working with/tried?

Comment: Yes it can be done, but what have you tried so far? :)

Comment: @Xavi I answered you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate every cell, parse its content and set the background color:

```
function updateColors () {
    $("td").css("background-color", "white");
    $("td").each (function () {
       var $cCell = $(this);
       if (Number ($cCell.text()) <= -1) {
          $cCell.css("background-color", "#FF0000");
       }
    });
}

updateColors();

// http://stackoverflow.com/a/7804973/1420197    
var allCells = document.querySelectorAll("td");
for (var i = 0; i < allCells.length; ++i) {
    allCells[i].addEventListener("DOMCharacterDataModified", function () {
        console.log(this.innerText);
        updateColors();
    });
}
```

### Demo

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hcekF/2/)

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer but it not working ,,when i inline edit the td and enter the value -2 it not changing the color it remains the same color

Comment: @Xavi Do you use `contentEditable` cells?

Comment: yes i am using,so when content edited the it check the content in cell and assign the color in cell

Comment: thanks do but if i remove the value in td it also showing red color and if i enter new values like 2 it also showing red color

Comment: @Xavi Cannot reproduce. See the gif image.

Answer (score 0):

Give an ID to your cell, like `<td id='cellID'>34</td>` then do this in jquery:

```
var _cellValue = $("#cellID").html();
_cellValue = parseInt(_cellValue);
if (_cellValue=<-1){
  $("#cellID").css("background-color","#FF0000");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Briefly tested, hope this helps:

```
var colors = {
    black: {
        num: 1,
        hex: '000'
    },
    red: {
        num: 2,
        hex: 'f00'
    },
    grey: {
        num: 3,
        hex: '333'
    }
};

function getColor(num) {
    var color = '#fff'; // default
    $.each(colors, function(index, obj) {
        if (parseInt(obj.num)===parseInt(num)) {
            color = '#'+obj.hex;
        }
    });
    return color;
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#mytable td', function() {
    var current = $(this).text();
    if (current.length > 0 && !isNaN(current)) {
        $(this).css('background-color', getColor(current));
    }
    else {
        // NaN, Set default color, handle errors, etc...
        $(this).css('background-color', '#fff');
    }
});
```