# Prefilling a form feild using dispachEvent doesn't work in IE, working fine in rest all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

my app was created using React. By using dispatchEvent I am trying to prefill the form field value using JS. It is working fine in all browsers but not in IE 11.

IE console is showing object doesn't support error.

The code I have used to prefill the form field.

```
$(document.body).on('change', '#retailer', function() {

        var retail_val = $(this).val();

        //Storing the retailer value in the respective hidden text field.
        if (retail_val != "0") {
            var el = document.getElementById("text_6551650686371-InputField");
            el.value = retail_val;
        //calling the function
            doEvent(el, 'input');

        }
        if (retail_val == "0") {
            var el = document.getElementById("text_6551650686371-InputField");
            el.value = "";
          //calling the function
            doEvent(el, 'input');

        }
});
function doEvent(obj, event) {
         event = new Event(event, {
            target: obj,
            bubbles: true
        });

        return obj ? obj.dispatchEvent(event) : false;
    }
```

[This is the error screenshot in IE 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVqCH.png)
NOTE: I tried with .val() method, as my app was created using react it is not working. Please help me to pre-fill the form field value in IE also. Additionally when I change the tab the value in the field is going off.

Comment: Why don't you use `jQuery.Event` and `.trigger()`?

Comment: How exactly I need to place and where can I trigger? Please suggest me the a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40391974/1677234), it may work if you change event name to "textinput" ( do this after checking browser )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to trigger an event, but I think this should do it:

```
$("#text_6551650686371-InputField").val(retail_val).trigger("input");
```

Comment: I have used the above code, but it is updated in the front end actual value attribute of the input is not updating. I think this application is done in react may be that is giving a conflict?? The above code which I have posted is working fine in all browsers except IE.