# Characters count in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do a "twitter like" character counter in a `contenteditable` `div`. I want to limit the user to typing a max of 140 characters.

I used jQuery to count the characters and show the remaining, but it doesn't count the Enter key (new line) as a character. I need to count the new lines too.

I tried to use a `textarea`, but I need to specify the `max-height` for the scrollbar be visible only on the max-height. There is no limit of lines or characters.

**DEMO:**
https://jsfiddle.net/oLomzakh/

Can you help me figure out how to include the new line count on the character count?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wdowosv4/ works fine for me. the scrollbar is only visible when there are several lines of text (in chrome and FF and IE11). certain browsers may vary in the presentation, but that's preferable to an inconsistent counter.

Comment: @dandavis I think he wants the box to be small, and grow with the content that's added to it, up to a certain `max-height` - at which point the scroll bar appears.

Comment: @Martin: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/pew3mbyd/ ?  that's a trivial adjustment for a textarea...

Comment: @dandavis Probably more like this: https://jsfiddle.net/pew3mbyd/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Firstly, working code:](https://jsfiddle.net/oLomzakh/3/)

```
maxCharacters = 140;

$('#char-count').text(maxCharacters);

$('#text-area').bind('input', function() {

    var count = $('#char-count');
    var characters = $(this).text().length;
    var newlines = $($(this).html()).length;

    if (!!newlines) newlines -= 1;

    characters += newlines;

    if (characters > (maxCharacters - 11)) {
        count.addClass('over');
    } else {
        count.removeClass('over');
    }
    count.text(maxCharacters - characters);

});
```

## Now, an explanation:

It seems `content-editable` renders new lines using HTML (at least in Webkit). Adding a `debugger;` statement in the event handler, and checking the value of `$(this).html()` will reveal that:

[image]

As you can see there are both `div`'s and `br`'s in there.

That's where `var newlines = $($(this).html()).length;` comes in. This will count the children of the element (including both `div`'s and `br`'s). We need to also adjust `newlines` by -1 because once edited, there is always a remaining `div` or `br`.

We can add this to our `$(this).text()` value to get the real character count.

Comment: On chrome the first enter counts twice and on firefox when the text is deleted the counter is 139 cause stil a br in the div

Comment: Is there a way to detect the enter key and then increase de counter?

Comment: If a user inputs only whitespace, should that count as characters, or 0?

Comment: As an aside, [contenteditable might not be the best for what you want](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8694125/1007638). As the linked answer states, you will need to also somehow track clipboard events like cut and paste. Why don't you style a `<textarea>` instead? Is that possible given your context?

Comment: whitespaces counts as charcters

Comment: with content editable I can use `max-height` to show the scrollbar only on the max height of the div. I can't find a way to do the same with `textarea` [as you can see](https://jsfiddle.net/ho5fatwz/)

Comment: you should use to `input` event so that alt IME and pasting (via mouse) affect the count.

Comment: type one character, then press enter, it should count 2, but it counts 1

Comment: If I am correct, it still doesn't show the character count INSIDE the `<div>` (this was asked)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use $.html() instead of $.text(), you'll be able to know when there is a \n, but with $.text() it won't count special chars.

You can use "this.innerText.length" property too, without jQuery, but it will count \r\n and not only 1 character for a new line.

EDIT : you can get the $.html() for example and replace each new line `<br>` by only one character, then you just have to get the property length of that result.

Comment: '$.html' works, but when the text is deleted the count is 136

Comment: You can press backspace again, because there is an invisible char here

Comment: `innerText` is not xbrowser compat, and is different in different browsers where it is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Martins answer is correct. 
But if you want white spaces and special characters to count as well you need this:

```
maxCharacters = 140;

$('#char-count').text(maxCharacters);

$('#text-area').bind('input', function() {

    var count = $('#char-count');
    var characters = $(this).text().length;

    if (characters > (maxCharacters - 11)) {
        count.addClass('over');
    } else {
        count.removeClass('over');
    }
    count.text(maxCharacters - characters);
});
```

I removed these 3 lines of code:

```
var newlines = $($(this).html()).length;

if (!!newlines) newlines -= 1;

characters += newlines;
```