# IE detect innerHtml change

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

I create a div and set it's contenteditable to true to create a rich textarea.
now I want to listen the oninput event, but in IE, there is no such event. Also, I can't use onpropertychange because textNode in IE can't attach events.
Do I have to use onkeydown,onpaste? (I hope not)

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events

Comment: Not quite the same,I want this event fire when the content has change,like input event in firefox

Comment: Note: `oninput` works in WebKit, so you might want to use it for Chrome/Safari at the very least, although feature detection might be a bit of a problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
name: <INPUT 
      NAME="realname" 
      onFocus = "window.status='Enter your name'" 
      onBlur  = "window.status=window.defaultStatus" 
      ><BR>
email: <INPUT 
      NAME="email" 
      onFocus = "window.status='Enter your email address'" 
      onBlur  = "window.status=window.defaultStatus" 
      >
```

as an example of running scripts when a user clicks in a text-input. This will work with a text area as well.

Comment: He's talking about a "rich textarea", basically `<div contentEditable>....</div>`

Comment: @Manishearth - thanks for that, maybe should have read more clearly.