# keypress event and offset in DOM contenteditable paragraph element

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16429006/841108) about `contenteditable` and rich text editing. I'm using HTML5 and JavaScript in a recent Firefox (21 beta 7 on Linux).

I want a content-editable `<p>` paragraph (or perhaps later, `<div>` block element) in which the user input words are shown in two different ways (probably `<span class='name'>` and `<span class='word'>`) depending if they are known or not. So if the user has typed <kbd>foo john</kbd> and `foo` is an unknown word but `john` is a known name the two words would be rendered differently, and the editable paragraph would contain

```
<p><span class='word'>foo</span> <span class='name'>john</span></p>
```

When I am getting a `keypress` event I know its `target` element. But how can I know the character offset in that element. In other words, if the element is some text node or span containing <kbd>jon</kbd> and if the caret is after <kbd>jo</kbd> and before <kbd>n</kbd> and if I'm typing the <kbd>h</kbd> character how can I get the offset 2?

Of course I have a JavaScript `knownname` function which returns `null` if its argument -some string- is not a known name but a plain word, and some true value if it is known.

BTW, I want plain JavaScript. Later, that JavaScript will be generated (and I am beginning to learn how to do that generator).

Comment: Take a look at [selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection) and [range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/range). :)

Comment: @DaggNabbit: Thanks! do you have some good tutorial material (preferably website) to advise me to read?

Comment: Is a `contenteditable` paragraph the good approach for simple rich text editor, or should I use `textarea`? Then, how can I change the style or look of individual words inside?

Comment: [Tim Down](http://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down) is pretty much the authority on this stuff as far as I know, you might want to look at the source of his [rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library. `contenteditable` is the way to go, you can't style individual parts of a textarea.