# how to create input or textarea (place typing text) with div element

Tags: css, html

I want to create one place for typing text like input or `textarea` with `div` element but I don't know about it.

Please tell me about it.

Also I want this `div` like input mean when click on it cursor to be Blinker.

Comment: Check this [**link**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/Hp87R/). Is this what you want?

Comment: yes my friend how to do it?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Comment: How come you don't want to use the HTML input or textarea elements? They can be styled with css and can respond to javascript events.  Plus, it's semantic and accessible.  Just curious.

Comment: @Harry Right on - you answered the question that was asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below is what you are looking for.

**HTML**

```
<div id="editable" contentEditable="true"></div>
```

**CSS** (Not required, but just to make the DIV look like Input Box)

```
#editable{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/Hp87R/)

**Note:** Refer to Aditya's answer for Browser Compatibility. If you want to support any browser outside of that list, please do not use this.

Comment: yes, you can style the div using CSS (like I have done in the sample above)

Comment: so my friend can I when press enter in this div change event?

Comment: @mamal10: You would find this SO post useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you want : http://jsbin.com/eqEPAci/1/edit

CSS:

```
.styles{
        height:30px;
    width:286px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #5E5E5E;
    padding:0px 5px;
        background-color: #000000;
        color:#BFBFBF;
        outline: none;
        input-align: center;
}

.abs-centered {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#actual-input{
  height:26px;
  padding:0px;
  width:100%;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:transparent;
  border:0px;
  outline-style:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#25383C">
  <div class="styles abs-centered">
    <input id="actual-input" name="name" type="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternative:

```
<div contentEditable></div>
```

[Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable)

Answer (score 0):

use `contentEditable="true"` attribute for div

like this :

```
<div contentEditable="true"></div>
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hp87R/2/)

but be careful that this is **HTML5** and old browsers don't support it