# How can I send contents of a div as a POST parameter?

Tags: php, html, post

I have this Code:

```
<div contenteditable="true"><p><?php echo $row[1]; ?></p></div>
```

Can I take the contents of the div and send them as a POST parameter in order to use them in the PHP. It would be good if I can use: onchange="this.form.submit()".

Thanks!

Comment: you echoed the contents, so you already have it in a variable. so what exactly do you want to do with `$row[1]` ?

Comment: The contents can be changed by the user. I use it like <input> but in this way I don't have fixed width.

Comment: @user3294900 - Have you ever looked into using [`stream_context_create`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php)?

Comment: why not put it in an textarea, when they hit 'submit' its posted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to post contents of `div` tags, as this is only possible on form elements. The workaround for this would be to use some Javascript that populates a `hidden` field when a form is submitted, and the `hidden` field is posted instead.

Observe the following HTML. See that there is an `onsubmit` event attached to the `form` element. What we're saying to the browser here is when the form is submitted, first call the Javascript function `process`, and only submit if said function returns `true`:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php" onsubmit="javascript: return process();">
  <input type="hidden" id="hidden" name="content" vlaue="<?php echo $row[1] ?>">
  <div contenteditable="true" id="content"><p><?php echo $row[1] ?></p></div>
  <button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

This would be your Javascript. What you're doing is getting the `innerHTML` of the element with the id `content` and assigning it to the `value` of the element with the id `hidden` and return `true` so the form can be successfully submitted:

```
<script>
function process() {
  document.getElementById("hidden").value = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
  return true;
}
</script>
```

And in the `process.php` file, just output the posted content:

> var_dump("Posted content: " . $_POST['content']);

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way if I don't want the button? I want to be on change

Comment: That's slightly more tricky - I don't think certain browsers support this. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1411296/1155208