# JQuery is not picking up on changes to a div

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I'm trying to count the amount of `<img>` tags in a div whenever a div is updated. The HTML is simply:

```
<div id="Description" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Whenever the div's contents are changed, I want JQuery to count the the number of images in the div. So I wrote this:

```
$(document).on('change', '#Description', function(e) {
    var filenumber = $('#Description img').length;
    alert(filenumber);
});
```

The problem is that nothing happens. I don't get an alert when I type stuff into the div or insert an image. Am I overlooking something simple? I'm using CKEditor as the rich text editor for the div but I don't think its the problem, however I'm no expert.

Here is a JSFiddle to demo the problem http://jsfiddle.net/jLnLmspn/1/

Comment: See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events

Comment: That's because you're inserting text instead of HTML

Comment: Look at the source code while you type into the div and you will see that it only updates strings of text and `<div>`s

Comment: The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no javascript expert, but I don't think the onchange event can be used in conjunction with a `div` element, only input ones. As such, to get the behavior you want, the most obvious way I can think is to check for actual `input` events (literally the `input` event) or to periodically poll. To use the input event (which I *think* is HTML5 specific, maybe?), you could do something like:

```
$(document).on('input', '#Description', function(e) {
    var filenumber = $('#Description img').length;
    alert(filenumber);
});
```

Be aware though, this will fire a *lot*.

Comment: how did you know that 'input' is an event? i can't see in the docs anywhere http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: @JosanIracheta is correct - when looking for specs the Mozilla docs are _quite_ nice.

Comment: This works when I type into the div. But I am also using Javascript to  inserts data in such as an img tag. It doesn't pick up on that insertion. How could I pick up on that?

Comment: If you're using javascript to insert text there, you can programmatically make it trigger the event `$('#Description').trigger('input')`, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

Try typing `<img>` at `#Description`

```js
$('#Description').on("keyup keydown", function(e) {
    var html = $.parseHTML(e.target.textContent)
    , filtered = $(html).filter("img")
    , imgs = filtered.is("*") 
             ? filtered.length + " images found" 
             : "0 images found";
    console.log(imgs);              
});
```

```css
#Description {
height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Description" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onchange event isn't firing because you're typing into a contenteditable div, not an input element. See this thread for more info on how to do something similar to onchange with a div: [contenteditable change events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events)