# Submitting an h2 tag with a form to a server?

Tags: php, html, forms

So here's what I'd like to do. Here's the code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2 contenteditable="true">Editable Content WOO</h2>
  <div class="box-a box"></div>
  <div class="box-b box"></div>
  <div class="box-c box"></div>
    <form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <textarea id="textbox" class="editor" name="editor" contenteditable="true"></textarea>
    <input class="save" type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
</div>
```

The `<h2>` tag is content editable, I'd like to make that the "name" of said submission. I'm doing a project in school, and it's basically a simple HTML5 live editor, but I like the look of the `contenteditable <h2>`. I think of it like Google Doc's title.

Comment: to submit the details to server, you should put the h2 inside the form tag

Comment: This won't work because it is not an input type

Comment: formatted code, removed extraneous details

Comment: What's the purpose of the `contenteditable="true"` on the textarea? Does that change the behaviour in some way?

Comment: Quite an interesting question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to use it as the title? Than just place an input field inside your form giving it a h2 layout.
When submitting, you can get the value from "title" in php to use it as a title to save your item.

Submitting a h2 with a form directly is not possible (then you should use something like JavaScript or JQuery)

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" name="title" class="h2" />
  <div class="box-a box"></div>
  <div class="box-b box"></div>
  <div class="box-c box"></div>
    <textarea id="textbox" class="editor" name="editor" contenteditable="true"></textarea>
    <input class="save" type="submit" value="Save">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Ahhh okay, I was thinking I needed to do this, but I wasn't sure if there would be a way to do it, especially with how much HTML5 has expanded. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

H2 can not be submitted with form 
You can add input box and make style exactly same as h2 or you can keep your current setup and add one more hidden field in the form. but you need to write some js code when content of h2 changes you can update this hidden field.

to know how [follow this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events)