# How to restrict user from entering # & . in the label while content editable is true?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using Bootstrap form builder, I want to know how I can restrict user from entering `#` and `.` into the property of a label, where `contenteditable` is true.

I want this to be implemented for any random label that is going to be edited. How to do that?

I am aware of the ascii values for that but for all the labels present in that page when content editable is true i want user not to input `#` and `.` into it.

My label sample is this:

```
<label>
    <strong contenteditable="true">Telephone</strong>
</label>
```

I tried using this but does not prevent it from typing # & .

```
$('body').on('paste input', '[contenteditable]', function(data) {
var text = $(this).text();
    if (text == '#' || text == '.'){
        console.log('hi');
    data.preventDefault();
} 
});
```

working now

```
$('body').on('paste input', '[contenteditable]', function(data) {
var text = $(this).text();
var regax1 = /#/;
var regax2 = /./;
if (text.match(regax1)) {
   var newText = text.replace('#', '');
   $('strong').text(newText);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: See this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events)

Comment: thanks for the response but this is for the specific field input. In my case there are unknown number of labels depending upon user drag & drop. For all the labels this should be applied how to do it...

Comment: that link describes a general method for attaching event listeners while using the contendEditable attribute. You can use that to listen on any elements - a specific field input, if need be. Am I missing something?

Comment: i have edited the post to show ine of the label. check it.

Comment: Formatting text, removing unnecessary tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('body').on('paste input', '[contenteditable]', function(data) {
        var text = $(this).text();

        if(text.match(/#/g).length > 0) {
            var newText = text.replace('#', '');
            $('strong').text(newText);
        } 
    });
});
```

Here's a pen: http://codepen.io/ciprian/pen/BNyqbv

Comment: It is showing me type error: TypeError: text.match(...) is null

Comment: ya it is working but when i copied that one in my application is showed me this error on my console

Comment: Is it showing you that error when you type '#' or when you type any character?

Comment: but what if i also need to disable the dot character. I tried for dot but it is working unexpected after that...

Comment: That's great. Make sure you use a class for `strong`, unless you want all `strong` elements to work like this.

Comment: You are right, the dot matches any element. Try `\.`

Comment: Yes. `var regax2 = "/\./";`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know bootstrap form builder but you can do this easily using onkeyup event on every input.

When user press a key, look keycode and if you don't like this key, remove the last character.
Or on every onkeyup use regexp to replace bad character.

Comment: Maybe `preg_replace()`, because the user might copy a word containing the forbidden characters, and the script would not detect them.