# Maxlength for DIV like Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to **set the maximum text-length of the div.**

I have this **HTML** code here:

```
<div contentEditable=true data-ph="Subject of this message" maxlength = "10" id = "discussionsubject">
</div>
```

In which I made the `DIV` to act like `textarea`. Now, I tried to set it's `maxlength` by `10` but it doesn't worked.

Also tried this few codes found in other SO questions which seems not working fine with me:

```
 var myDiv = $('#discussionsubject');
 myDiv.text(myDiv.text().substring(0,10));
```

Also tried this code but still doesn't work:

```
$("div#discussionsubject).text(function(index, currentText) {
    return currentText.substr(0, 10);
});
```

Please, need help..

Comment: Your second batch of code should work - what does it do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope following code may help you:

```
//Maximum number of characters
var max = 10;

$('#editable_div').keydown(function(e) {
    var keycode = e.keyCode;

    //List of keycodes of printable characters from:

        var printable = 
        (keycode > 47 && keycode < 58)   || // number keys
        keycode == 32 || keycode == 13   || // spacebar & return key(s) (if you want to allow carriage returns)
        (keycode > 64 && keycode < 91)   || // letter keys
        (keycode > 95 && keycode < 112)  || // numpad keys
        (keycode > 185 && keycode < 193) || // ;=,-./` (in order)
        (keycode > 218 && keycode < 223);   // [\]' (in order)

    if (printable) {

        return $(this).text().length <= max; 
    }
});
```

***UPDATE***
For managing copy and paste actions, you need to manage following event handler:

```
 document.getElementById("discussionsubject").addEventListener("input", function () {
            alert("input event fired");
        }, false);
```

Now merge the logic from first code block into updated event handler.

Comment: This code is what i've been lookin' for! Geez, Thanks

Comment: You're code seems to work fine. However, copying more than 10 characters of text and paste it into the div also works. How would I trap this? Please help

Comment: If you wish to remove limit of 10 characters in div then set 'max' variable value to the number of character you want to insert in DIV. It will be appreciated if you mark this as answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but i think you misunderstood my explanation. As I've said in the previous comment, For example when I copied `(Ctrl+C)` 20 characters of string and then pasted `(Ctrl+V)` it to the text-editor it allows it to be pasted so your code above doesn't work. Gets?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your second code is that you are missing closing quotes:

```
$("div#discussionsubject )
                        ^ -- required (")
```

Sample demo:

```js
$(function() {
  $('div.edit-box').text(function(_, txt) {
    return txt.substring(0, +$(this).data('length'));
  });
});
```

```css
div.edit-box {
  border: 1px ridge grey;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-length="10" class='edit-box'>
  Hello there everyone ...
</div>
<div data-length="20" class='edit-box'>
  Good day !! This goes another line ...
</div>
```