# Backspace deletes whole span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backspace

Is it possible to prevent span deletion with backspace?

```html
<div class="form-control" contenteditable="true">
  <span class="correct-answer">
    <span contenteditable="false">The correct answer is (A) 1 to 2. </span>
    <span class="sentence" num="11">dgsdgsg. sgsdgs sgsgs.</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pvj64px9/1/

```
The correct answer is (B) 2 to 3. and `Choice A (1 to 2) is incorrect. ` must not be deleted.
```

Comment: sure, but you'll need JS to check..

Comment: It's ok, if it fixes the issue! :)

Comment: Added jsfiddle example.

Comment: Fixed my gramatics mistake - `The correct answer is (B) 2 to 3.` and `Choice A (1 to 2) is incorrect. ` must not be deleted.

Comment: might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your parent container to have contenteditable="false"

```
<div id="window-kitkat" class="form-control" contenteditable="false">
```

and set the individual elements you want as editable to true, e.g.,

```
<span class="sentence" num="10" contenteditable="true">jfbgfdgdf sgdsgsd.</span>
```