# How to I prevent deletion of contenteditable span?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a `contenteditable` `span`. But if, as the user, I delete all the text within the span, the span disappears and is no longer editable (still in the DOM though). How do I prevent this?

I'm seeing this problem in both Chrome and FF.

Here's what I've tried:

```html
<div class="subgroup" contenteditable="false" style="border: 1px solid red;">
   <span class="header editable" contenteditable="true">initial contents</span>
</div>
```

I put `contenteditable="false"` on the parent element based on [this answer from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32646076/1431728), but the result is the same whether or not that attribute is present on the parent.

Of course, I could have JS intercept keypresses to prevent the user from completely clearing the contents, but that's a bad UX. I'd much prefer a pure HTML solution in any event.

Comment: `.subgroup span:empty { padding-right:1em;}` should help you find out a way.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, that works, thanks! I used `1px` instead of `1em`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In writing up this question, I discovered a solution. For others who might need it: put a border on the `span`.

But there, as suggested by @G-Cyrillus, a better solution is to add padding to the `span` when the node is empty:

```html
<style>
.subgroup span:empty { padding-right:1em;}
</style>
<div class="subgroup" contenteditable="false" style="border: 1px solid red;">
   <span class="header editable" contenteditable="true">initial contents</span>
</div>
```

Anyone have a better solution?