# How to add a class to a div created inside a contenteditable element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Here is the example code:

```
<div>
  Text..
  <div id="editable-editor" contenteditable="true">Some Text Here...</div>
</div>
```

If press enter inside the `#editable-editor` after `Some Text` it will create a `<div>Here...</div>` element for the text Here.

How do I add the jquery-ui `draggable` class to the `<div>Here...</div>` element to make it dragabble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to reference [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1411296/1008741). Essentially, there is no cross-browser guaranteed way to know when someone has added new content to your contenteditable element. You can guess, however.

```
$("#editable-editor").keydown(function () {
   $(this).children('div').each(function () {
        $(this).draggable();
   });
});
```

Simply listen for key events and add draggable to your new divs.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But this is dragging all the <div> elements if i drag the first <div>element.. I should be able to drag the individual <div>.

Comment: Hey @Ketha Kavya I've changed my answer. See if that works better for you.

Comment: No this didn't work its not dragging any <div> element.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

$('div', '#editable-editor').each(function (i) {

$(this).addClass('ui-widget-content');
 $(this).draggable();

});

Comment: Hi please check this [fiddle-dragAround](http://jsfiddle.net/jskBJ/1h89jmLr/1/) @KethaKavya

Comment: I have asked it for a <div> with contenteditable=true which creates a children div dynamicallly not  just for a <div> element with children.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `keypress` , `change` events , `.has()` , `.not()`

```js
$("#editable-editor")
  .on({
    "keypress": function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        $(this).append("<div>Here...</div>")
        .change()
      }
    },
    "change": function() {
      if ($(this).has("div")) {
        $("div", this).not(".ui-draggable").draggable()
      }
    }
  })
```

```css
.draggable {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Text..
  <div id="editable-editor" contenteditable="true">Some Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @KethaKavya _"This isn't working."_ Can describe details ?

Comment: Its appending an additional <div>Here</div> and its dragging that additionally added div but not the div that is created from the contenteditable div.

Comment: Is requirement to 1) only create sinle `div` containing text "here" at keypress of enter key ? 2) add `draggable` attribute to `Text` ? 3) add `draggable` attribute to `contentEditable` element ?

Comment: for a `div` with  ` contenteditable` it will create a div automatically when an enter key is pressed. So for the div that is created when the enterkey is pressed i want to make that each individual `div` to be draggable.

Comment: @KethaKavya _"for a div with ` contenteditable` it will create a div automatically when an enter key is pressed. So for the div that is created when the enterkey is pressed i want to make that each individual div to be draggable. "_ Yes . Tried stacksnippets ? If press "Enter" , `div` should be appended having text "Here..." which should be draggable