# Excel-like Updating a table without a button in PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to update a row of a table. So when I click on a cell, I want it to be transformed into text box, so I used this:

```
<td contenteditable></td>
```

And then, when the content of a `<td>` is changed, I need to send it through AJAX to update it in the server without clicking on a button, so it will use the `.change(function())`.

I tried to get the content changed into a variable:

```
$("TD").change(function()
{
//Here I want to set the row ID:
var rowid = '<?php echo $row['id'] ?>';
var name = $("#emp_name").val();
var position = $("#position").val();
var salary = $("#salary").val();
$.ajax
        ({
            url: 'update.php', 
            type: 'POST', 
            data: {dataId: rowid, data1: name, data2: position, data3: salary},//Now we can use $_POST[data1];
            dataType: "text",

            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data=="success")
                {
                    //alert("Data added");
                    $("#before_tr").before("<tr><td>"+emp+"</td><td>"+pos+"</td><td>"+sal+"</td></tr>");
                    $("#emp_name").val("");
                    $("#position").val("");
                    $("#salary").val("");
                }
            },

            error:function(data)
            {
                if(data!="success")
                {
                    alert("data not added");
                }
            }

        });
});
```

The problem is how to know which row is changed to send it via `AJAX` ? I am not getting any errors even when data not updated.

Here is the update.php code:

```
try
{
        $rowid = $_POST['dataId'];
        $emp_name = $_POST['data1'];
        $pos = $_POST['data2'];
        $sal = $_POST['data3'];

        $upd = "UPDATE emp SET name = :emp_name, position = :pos, sal = :sal WHERE id  = :rowid";
        $updStmt = $conn->prepare($upd);
        $updStmt->bindValue(":rowid", $rowid);
        $updStmt->bindValue(":emp_name", $emp_name);
        $updStmt->bindValue(":pos", $pos);
        $updStmt->bindValue(":sal", $sal);
        $updStmt->execute();

        echo "success";
}

catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

HTML:

```
<tbody>
                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";
                $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();
                $res=$stmt->fetchAll();
                foreach($res as $row){
                ?>
                <tr id=""<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"">
                    <td contenteditable><?php echo $row['emp_name'] ?></td>
                    <td contenteditable><?php echo $row['position'] ?></td>
                    <td contenteditable><?php echo $row['salary'] ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
```

Comment: With `$(this)` you will get the changed td cell.

Comment: `<tr id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">`

`var rowid = $(this).attr('id');`

Comment: Still nothing updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading your data with PHP you need to keep the row id in your html:

```
<tr id="<?php echo $yourList["id"]; ?>">
<td contenteditable></td>
</tr>
```

Then in your javascript you can catch it using the `parent()` jquery function

```
$("TD").change(function()
{
//Here I want to set the row ID:
var rowid =$(this).parent().attr("id");

......
```

**UPDATE**

Check this example, I have added listeners to detect contenteditable `td` changes, I think you shall add it too , refer to this [contenteditable change events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events) for defining proper change events on contenteditable fields.

**Explanation:**

The contenteditable does not trigger change events, this work around is used to detect the focus event of the `td` using jquery on method and event delegation. The original content is saved in the `td` jquery data object `$this.data('before', $this.html());` . Then when the user leaves the field or triggers any of the events `'blur keyup paste input'`, the current content is compared to the content in the data object, if it differs, the change event of the `td` is triggered.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  
  $('table').on('focus', '[contenteditable]', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('before', $this.html());
    return $this;
  }).on('blur keyup paste input', '[contenteditable]', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('before') !== $this.html()) {
        $this.data('before', $this.html());
        $this.trigger('change');
    }
    return $this;
  });
  
  $("TD").change(function()
  {
    //Here I want to set the row ID:
    var rowid = $(this).parent().attr("id");

    $("#res").html(rowid);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" width="500px">
  <tr  id="1222">
    <td contenteditable></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr  id="55555">
    <td contenteditable></td>
  </tr>
  
 </table>

Row Id : <span id="res"></span>
```

Comment: I tried it and try to see the id in the console but nothing appeared

Comment: show me the html generated after adding the id attribute to the `tr`

Comment: I will add the html in my question

Comment: `<tr id=""<?php echo $row['id'] ?>""> ` is wrong, it must be `<tr id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">`

Comment: still can't see the id, the result of `console.log(rowid);` is none

Comment: with the devtools, inspect the `tr` line and make sure there is a valid id value, please post the markup you see

Comment: Still the same, empty result in the console, I tried `$("TR")` instead of `$("TD") and still the same

Comment: it works, but can you explain in details what happened in the listener (from `$('table')...`)

Comment: The contenteditable does not trigger change events, this work around is used to detect the `focus` event of the td using jquery `on` method and event delegation. The original content is saved in the `td`jquery data object $this.data('before', $this.html());. Then when the user leaves the field or triggers any of the events `'blur keyup paste input'`, the current content is compared to the content in the data object, if it differs, the change event of the `td` is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr row_id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"> ></tr>
```

In Your Ajax

```
var rowid = $(this).attr('row_id');
```

Comment: It would be better to use `data-`attribute in conjunction with jquery's `data()`

Comment: you mean `<td id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">` ?