# Dynamic title update from contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, title, data-uri

I'm making a little data URI for taking notes

```
data:text/html
<title>Text Editor</title>
<body>
  <div contenteditable class="text" id="title">Title...</div>
  <div contenteditable class="text">Body...</div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ab3hh3ka/

I'm wondering what kind of JavaScript could I use to dynamically update the title of the page as you write in the `#title` field. The goal is to be able to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to be to save the file with the title already in place.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "a little data URI". This is a data URI: https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [contenteditable change events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events)

Comment: To edit the title using JQuery, run `$("title").text($("#title").text());` The question I linked to has data about how to get this to run when contenteditable changes.

Comment: Thanks, I tried looking for a solution but found nothing

Comment: I must add, I can't use JQuery as is a data URI, meaning all code has to be input in the address bar.

Comment: Are you making a bookmarklet?

Comment: Yes, aadams solution did the trick. I often find myself at work without external internet connection, but since we work through a browser in an intranet, the bookmarklet becomes very handy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For modern browsers, you can watch for the HTML5 input event for contenteditable elements like so (pure JS):

```
document.getElementById("title").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    var value = e.srcElement.innerHTML;
    document.title = value;
}, false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ab3hh3ka/3/