# Fire Jquery "onchange" event on a content editable DIV

Tags: jquery

I am currently using `keyup` event.

```
$('body').on("keyup", '.emojionearea-editor', function (event) {  });
```

But i want to make a jquery event that automatically fire as the content within "contenteditable" DIV changes ?

how can i make change event in jquery.?

Comment: How that change will happen ? with `keyup` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [contenteditable change events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events)

Comment: i want to trigger automatically , as the content within div changes. @HimanshuUpadhyay

Comment: @NisargShah .. this is javascript function how i can add it to jquery??

Comment: @ghayourabbas `$('body').on("input", '.emojionearea-editor', function (event) {  });`