# Detect table cell change on user edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I'm trying to detect html table cell change on user input. When I click on table cell I can type text in it, but my .change function is not triggered. However on page load when data are populated from database, for every table cell change change function is fired. I can not figure why. Can you help. 
My code below:

```
    <div id="table" class="table-editable">
        <table id="myTable" style="width:100%" class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Link</th>
                <th>Naslov</th>
                <th>Lokacija</th>
                <th>Cijena</th>
                <th>Telefon</th>
                <th>Posjet</th>
                <th>Opis</th>
                <th>Prednosti</th>
                <th>Nedostaci</th>
                <th>Slike</th>
                <th>Select</th>
            {% for entry in entries %}
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                <td><a id="linkHouse_{{ forloop.counter }}" href="{{ entry.link }}">Link na oglas</a></td>
                <td contenteditable="true">{{ entry.header }}</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">{{ entry.location  }}</td>
                <td id="priceHouse_{{ forloop.counter }}" contenteditable="true">{{ entry.price  }}</td>
                <td id="contactHouse_{{ forloop.counter }}" contenteditable="true">{{ entry.contacts }}</td>
                <td id="visitedHouse_{{ forloop.counter }}" contenteditable="true">{{ entry.visited  }}</td>
                <td id="descriptionHouse_{{ forloop.counter }}" contenteditable="true">{% for line in entry.description.splitlines %} {{line}}<br> {% endfor %}</td>
                <td id="prosHouse_{{ forloop.counter }}" contenteditable="true" >{% for line in entry.pros.splitlines %} {{line}}<br> {% endfor %}</td>
                <td id="consHouse_{{ forloop.counter }}"contenteditable="true">{% for line in entry.cons.splitlines %} {{line}}<br> {% endfor %}</td>
                <td >
                    <a class="fancybox" target="_blank" data-fancybox="images" href="{% static "Pic/img_fjords_wide.jpg" %}"><img src="{% static "Pic/img_fjords_wide.jpg" %}" alt="" style="width:150px"></a>
                    <a class="hide fancybox" target="_blank" data-fancybox="images" href="{% static "Pic/img_lights_wide.jpg" %}"><img src="{% static "Pic/img_lights_wide.jpg" %}" alt=""></a>
                    <a class="hide fancybox" target="_blank" data-fancybox="images" href="{% static "Pic/img_mountains_wide.jpg" %}"><img src="{% static "Pic/img_mountains_wide.jpg" %}" alt=""></a>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                    <button id="delHouse_{{ forloop.counter }}" onclick="delHouse(this.id)">Delete</button>

                    <!--<input type="checkbox" name="delete{{ forloop.counter }}">-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>




$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#myTable td" )
  .change(function () {
        console.log("petar");
        var data = this.innerHTML;
        console.log("value="+data);
  })
  .change();
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Javascript's [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) method.

Or the [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) method.

```html
<div contenteditable oninput="console.log(this.innerHTML)">Change me (input)!</div>

<div contenteditable onblur="console.log(this.innerHTML)">Change me (blur)!</div>
```

[IE 6 & 8 and Opera Mini are not supported & IE 9 partial support](https://caniuse.com/#search=input), but either than that, it works!

If you want global support, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events) thread.

So your code would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#myTable td" )
    .input(function () {
          console.log("petar");
          var data = this.innerHTML;
          console.log("value="+data);
    })
  .input();
});
```

Comment: This way function is triggered on every character/keypad pressed. What I would like to achieve is type some text and then after all the text has been entered to trigger function, e.g on mouse move off cell (cell out of focus or something)

Comment: Did you check out [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur)?

Comment: That's the thing I was looking for. Rally appreciate help.