# Event listener on an element inside contenteditable

Tags: javascript, events, dom, contenteditable

How to detect if an element inside a contenteditable was changed?

Doing a MutationObserver on a  tag inside a content editable doesn't work.
Doing a 'input', 'keypress', 'keydown', 'change' doesn't work as well.
'click' event listener work, but I'm looking to find when the element was changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [contenteditable change events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events)