# show an element only if contentEditable div is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$('#story').on('keypress', function(){
 $('#btnsave').show();
});
```

```css
#story{
background:gold;
min-height:54px;
padding:9px;
}

#btnsave{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='story' contentEditable='true'>lorem ipsum</div>
<br>
<button id='btnsave'>SAVE</div>
```

I need to show `btnsave` only if `story` is changed.

`kyedown` and `keyup` don't work because of funcional and other keys included.

`keypress` seems to be ok, except `backspace` and `delete` - when pressing - nothing happens.

What to do?

Comment: use "input" event listener?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [contenteditable change events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('#story').on('keypress', function(){
    $('#btnsave').show();
});
```

To

```
document.getElementById("story").addEventListener("input", function() {
    $('#btnsave').show();
}, false);
```

OR

```
$('#story').on('input', (e) => {
    $('#btnsave').show();
});
```

Working Demo: https://codepen.io/OtakunityJL/pen/vVOvxV

Comment: Hi @JohnLouisDomincel. You can use `Ctrl+K` for placing your codes

Comment: What is the benefit of removing the use of jQuery for adding the listener, but still using it to show the button? Also, I would suggest not adding things like "accept this answer if correct" to members who aren't new to the site.

Answer (score 1):

as comment above you need to change `keypress` to `input`, and if you want to show only `#btnsave` when it different with previous content save original content as variable, then compare.

```js
var oldContent = $('#story').text();
var myTimeout;

$('#story').on('input', function() {
  clearTimeout(myTimeout);
  myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    if ($('#story').text() != oldContent) {
      $('#btnsave').show();
    }
    else{
       $('#btnsave').hide();
    }
  }, 200)

});

$('#btnsave').on('click', function(){
  oldContent = $('#story').text();
   $('#btnsave').hide();
})
```

```css
#story{
background:gold;
min-height:54px;
padding:9px;
}

#btnsave{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='story' contentEditable='true'>lorem ipsum</div>
<br>
<button id='btnsave'>SAVE</div>
```

Comment: This code tells when the content editable div has been interacted with, but not actually if the content is the same as it's original state.

Comment: added, check if edited content same with original state

Answer (score 0):

you can store the contents to a variable and check if it is different after blur() event. If it is different, then it changed.  http://jsfiddle.net/maxofpower/a4QNB/850/
another scenario is that user maybe press key but doesn't change anything...

```
var content = $('#story').html();
$('#story').blur(function() {
if (content!=$(this).html()){
    alert('change() called.');
    content = $(this).html();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle this kind is issue, you can trigger an event handler when the `div` with attribute `contenteditable` set to `true` loose the focus. Which can be done by setting an event handler on the `blur` event. The other way is to set a timer which wait a certain number of second in which a user doesn't type any thing on they keybord and manualy trigger disable the `contenteditable` and set the display property of the `button` to `block`

```js
var story = document.querySelector('#story');
var btn = document.querySelector('#btnsave');
story.addEventListener('blur', function(event){
 btn.style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
#btnsave {
 display: none;
}
#story{
  background:gold;
  min-height:54px;
  padding:9px;
}
```

```html
<div id='story' contentEditable='true'>lorem ipsum</div>
<br>
<button id='btnsave'>SAVE</div>
```