# Cant SUM on table td this code javascript how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cant Run SUM this code not working on table  How To FIX ?

PHP MYSQL, JAVASCRIPT

```
<td contenteditable="true" class="price"> </td>
<td contenteditable="true" class="price"> </td>
<td contenteditable="true" class="price"> </td>
<td contenteditable="true" class="price"> </td>
<td contenteditable="true" class="price"> </td>
<td contenteditable="true" class="price"> </td>

<script>
$(document).on("change", ".price", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".price").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".total").val(sum);
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="total" class="total" value=""  />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sum all values for table column based on class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293492/sum-all-values-for-table-column-based-on-class)

Comment: `on change` doesn't work on `td`, place `input` elements inside your `td`s then detect the change on those inputs

Comment: cant you help me place on td not input ?

Comment: Please don't ask the [same question twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56284859/how-to-fix-sum-of-multiple-input-fields-if-same-class-in-one-td-contenteditable)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <td contenteditable="true" price="10" class="price">10 </td>
<td contenteditable="true" price="10" class="price">10 </td>
<td contenteditable="true" price="10" class="price">10 </td>
<td contenteditable="true" price="10" class="price"> 10</td>
<td contenteditable="true" price="10" class="price"> 10</td>
<td contenteditable="true" price="10" class="price">10 </td>

<script>
$(document).ready(function)
    var sum = 0;
    $(".price").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).attr('price');
    });
    $(".total").val(sum);
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="total" class="total" value=""  />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('body').on('focus', '[contenteditable]', function() {
    const $this = $(this);
    $this.data('before', $this.html());
}).on('blur keyup paste input', '[contenteditable]', function() {
    const $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('before') !== $this.html()) {
        $this.data('before', $this.html());
        $this.trigger('change');
    }
});
$(document).on("change", ".price", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".price").each(function(){
    //console.log($(this).html());
        sum += +$(this).html();
    });
    $(".total").val(sum);
});
```

```css
.price{
width:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="3">
    <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="price"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="price"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="price"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="price"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="price"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="price"> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="total" class="total" value=""  />
```

For more detail please refer [contenteditable change events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events)

Comment: am using extension .php not .html bro, so not working when am input number on page .php , can you help me idea ?

Comment: it will works fine with .php extension file here is example link with .php file http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/mb7g-6smc