# How to trigger a function on an element with "contenteditable" attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I got a HTML table, that consists of:

```
<td contenteditable="true">
```

And I have some function:

```
f()
{
  alert("pew");
}
```

What should I do to call the function, when I click on my "td"?

```
OnClick="f();"
```

doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: it works checkout [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/85e7jfnx/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below link its has the same question.
[contenteditable change events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events)

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you link to solutions, please copy and paste any relevant bits into your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
function f()
{
  console.log("pew");
}
document.getElementById("mytd").addEventListener("click", function() {
    f()
}, false);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true" id="mytd">Content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thx, the problem was really stupid - I wrote code for one cell, and clicked another to test it...

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the semicolon from onclick="f()", should be work

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference.