# How many characters has the user deleted in WYSIWG element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to figure out how many characters are deleted by the user in a contenteditable div. I have a component that is rendered like this.

```
render(): JSX.Element | null {
    return (
      <div className="input-box">
        <div
          contentEditable={true}
          id={this.props.textId}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

`onContentChange` is added as an `eventListener` inside `componentDidMount()`.

I'm trying to print the event inside `onContentChange`, but I am not able to distinguish when the user has deleted one character or more, how can I find this out using the event or any other method?

Comment: Maybe this can help

Comment: @yunzen I think you missed something

Comment: You are right: Here the missing link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events

Comment: @yunzen this is not what I'm looking for, I strictly want to know how many characters are deleted

Comment: I don't think there is an easy solution to your answer. You need to distinguish between editing, deleting forwards ([Del]), deleting backwards ([Backspace]), cutting, selecting, etc.

Comment: @yunzen, exactly, that's why I skipped on going for that approach