# ContentEditable onChange function not working within html tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const checkQs = '<html>Hi everyone, I live in +++America+++.</html>';

let newStr = checkQs.replace(
  /\++(.*)\++/g,
  '<p contenteditable="true" onChange={handleChange} html={"$&"} >$&</p>',
);
```

In here I have replaced America with contentEditable, where I can update,
But `onChange` function is not working

Comment: Can you give a little bit of more context?

Comment: I donot think contentEditable will  trigger `change` events

Comment: You might have a solution in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events

Comment: @0xc14m1z what I try to do is
from a text, im getting a word using identifer +++, after getting that particular word
im sending it to contenteditor where i can edit that word . I have done upto that. I'm stuck with the onchange function where it is not working