# Listening to changes of contenteditable in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React.js and I want to listen for any change on this div (its `textContent`) with `contentEditable=true`.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div contentEditable=true > Hello </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div
  contentEditable="true"
  onInput={(e) => {
    console.log("woohoo!");
  }}>Hello</div>
```