# JavaScript save value of div element

Tags: javascript, html, input, savechanges

I have a simple text editor and I want to save its content, but it doesn't work because it is not an input element. It is a div element which has `contenteditable='true'` so I can write inside it. My question is that is there any way to save the characters that the user types in it?

I have tried the `onchange='saveValue(this)'` method but it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean with “is not working”? Is your callback not executed? Is it is, you are not retrieving the HTML?

Comment: I mean when I write inside the div element and refresh the page, the content disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events), along with guidance for modern browsers in some of the newer answers.