# React: How to catch contenteditable on history save?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I have this contentEditable div. I want to know how to catch the event when the element saves its html content. By doing `undo` it does not undoing 1 by 1 character each press. It actually saves the content history periodically.

For instance if I type `Hello world` fastly, when I undo it, it will undo the whole `Hello world`.

If I type `Hello world` then pause for 5 seconds, then type another `John Smith` fastly. If I press undo it will undo `John Smith` first, then it will undo `Hello World` after that.

My question is, how can I know when the history is saved? And what is the content for each history save?

Comment: Isn't that browser specific behaviour?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [contenteditable change events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events)