# How to activate an event with on() method when the value of a div tag is changed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am currently writing HTML and JS code in the following form, but when I put a new value in the div tag value, the event does not happen.

the Javascript code is

```
$('#CdText').on('input', function () {
    $('#CdText').innerHTML = concat($('#CdText').innerHTML, 'test');
});
```

HTML is

```
<div id="CdText" class="ui-state-highlight" contenteditable="true">1234</div>
```

The above code does not work.
However it works

```
$('#appInput').on('input', function () {
   $('#appInput').val(concat($('#appInput').val(), 'test'));
});
```

because HTML is

```
<input id="appInput" class="form-control ap-input">
  <div>1234</div>
</input>
```

By the way, changing $('#CdText').on('input', function () { as follows did not work.
$('#CdText').on('div', function () {
$('#CdText').on('change', function () {
$('#CdText').on('change', 'div', function () {

I hope I'm doing something wrong with Jquery's use of the on() method, but as of yet I haven't found what's wrong.

If you know how to write an event to be triggered every time something is entered into a div like the above, please let me know.

By the way, $('#CdText').on('input', function () { is properly contained in $(function () {}).
css of CdText div tag is inline-block. so it can write as input.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Jquery has `.html()`, similar to `.val()` in the second example; `.innerHTML` and `.value` only work for vanilla dom nodes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [contenteditable change events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events)

Comment: The `input` event fires when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element has been changed. This is likely why it is not working on a `<div>` element as that is not listed as a supported input element even though you have **contenteditable** set to ***true***.

Comment: Thanks.
I changed contenteditable tag. And then it worked I want.
Thank you to refer contenteditable.

Comment: @Matha Changed it how? To make this answer useful to future visitors, consider posting your answer.  Or, if it turns out [the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events) solves your problem, close this question as a duplicate of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `contenteditable` attribute while listening with `.on('input')`, however `.innerHTML` is made for vanilla JS, for jQuery you should use `.html()`.